# Magento 2 : How to show on product page, how many times product has been added to wishlist in single store

Tags: magento2, product, product-view, wishlist

On product detail page how many times a particular product has been added to Wishlist for simple product and configurable product in single store environment?

Trying below mentioned code:
Di.xml is as follows:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image">
        <plugin name="Wishlist_Count::Count" type="Wishlist\Count\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Wishcount"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Wishlist\Count\Plugin\Catalog\Product\Wishcount** file code

```
namespace Wishlist\Count\Plugin\Catalog\Product\View;
class Wishcount
{
    protected $_helper;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Wishlist\Count\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
    public function afterToHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $product = $subject->getProduct();
        $template = $subject->getTemplate();//view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
        $name = $subject->getNameInLayout();
        if ($product && $name == "product.info.media.image") {
            $result .= $this->_helper->renderWishlistCount( $product );
        }
        return $result;
    } }
```

Helper class code is as follows:

```
namespace Wishlist\Count\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_storeManager; 
    protected $_counts;
    protected $_registry;
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $_scopeConfig;    
    protected $_statusId = null;
    private $layoutFactory;
    private $_productTypeConfigurable;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $catalogProductTypeConfigurable,        
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->_productTypeConfigurable = $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
    }

    public function renderWishlistCount(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $html = '';

        $id    = $this->_storeManager->getStore(true)->getId();
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist');
        $html = $model->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['like' => "%$id%"])
            ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', ['like' => "%$product->getId()%"])

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what problem you are facing with your code? It will be helpful in finding the solution.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya some how it is not appearing on the detail page

Answer (score 1):

Please update your files with below code.

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery">
    <plugin name="Wishlist_Count::Count" type="Wishlist\Count\Plugin\Catalog\Product\View\Wishcount"/>
</type>
```

**Data.php**

```
public function renderWishlistCount(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $html = '';

    $id    = $this->_storeManager->getStore(true)->getId();
    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory');
    $wishlistCollection = $model->create()
        ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['like' => "%$id%"])
        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', ['eq' => $product->getId()]);
    $html .= count($wishlistCollection);
    return $html;
}
```

I would recommend not to use `objectManager`. You should inject the class to `__construct()`.